# Can't rename source code - get error 'Thread1: signal SIGABRT'

Tags: ios

I dragged an action to the ViewController.h area (which is my dayNight button), as shown:

```
//
//  ViewController.h
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

- (IBAction)dayNight:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)insulationClick:(id)sender;
```

Now I decide I want it to read:

```
- (IBAction)dayNightClick:(id)sender;
```

So I rename it manually as shown in above line.  I also rename it in the ViewController.m file from:

```
- (IBAction)dayNight:(id)sender{}
```

to:

```
- (IBAction)dayNightClick:(id)sender{}
```

When I execute the code I get an error as soon as I use my button.

If I manually rename it (without the word Click) it works again.

Why can't I manually modify the code line.  Is there another location where I must rename the code too?

The error is:

```
Thread1: signal SIGABRT
```

and points to this line of code in the main.m file:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
@autoreleasepool 
{
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
}
}
```

I'm sure this is a really basic question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I discovered is the following:

- Go to the story board (ie the view where you can see your GUI representation of your idevice)
- Click on the button you wish to rename (we are going to delete it)
- Click the button called "Show the connections inspector" (located near top right hand corner of xcode, and looks like a right pointing arrow in a black circle).
- There is a section called "Sent Events", and your button event will have a bubble drawn around it with a link to a second bubble with the name of your IBAction.
- Click on the tiny cross (x) in the second bubble to delete the event link.

Now you can start again and rename the button to whatever you like.  In my example I renamed it from:

```
(IBAction)dayNight:(id)sender{}
```

to:

```
(IBAction)dayNightClick:(id)sender{}
```

So this is renaming by deleting all references to the button and simply creating it again.  Note the other two places to delete it from are:

- In the *.h file, example I deleted this line:

  (IBAction)dayNight:(id)sender{}

and in the *.m file, example I deleted this code:

```
(IBAction)dayNight:(id)sender{} 
{
    // code in here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This happens because your storyboard / nib still points to the old name. The nib files are essentially just XML files in the background so what you need to do is to open your nib/storyboard go to the inspector that shows all the references. You will find that your old reference to the IBAction still exist there. Delete that by hitting the little cross and drag it into the ViewController again and connect it with the function you renamed it to.

Always remember to update both storyboard + .m if you change your method signature in your header file :)

Comment: I don't see a storyboard or nib file.  In the support Files folder I see .plist .string and .pch files, but not storyboard or nib in framework products or my main folder?

Comment: In your question, you said you "dragged an action" into the view controller right? Where did you drag it from? The GUI designer is the storyboard/nib (also has the extension .xib).

Comment: I should also mention that if you right click on your function and selected Refactor -> "Rename" next time, you won't run into this problem. It would automatically update the nib/storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The button has an associated target/selector which it calls when it's pressed. Look for a line that contains something like this:

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(dayNight:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

and change the selector here too.